# Heroku: managing different properties files in with maven

Tags: maven, heroku, properties

Maybe someone can help me. I have searched the web but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

I have a java application running on Heroku. I want to be able to have different properties files loaded for different Heroku instances (dev, test, prod), but I get java.io.FileNotFoundException. This is what I have in my pom.xml.

```
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.APP_ENVIRONMENT</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile.name>dev</profile.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.APP_ENVIRONMENT</name>
                    <value>test</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile.name>test</profile.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.APP_ENVIRONMENT</name>
                    <value>prod</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile.name>prod</profile.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0.34.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/profiles/${profile.name}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to customize the Maven build is described here:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml

You can create a settings file for each build type:

```
settings.xml       <-- Default
settings-dev.xml
settings-test.xml
settings-prod.xml
```

A production build could then be performed as follows:

```
heroku config:set MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH=settings-prod.xml
git push heroku master
```

## Details

The [Java buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/blob/master/bin/compile) supports a way to specify a custom Maven settings file.

By default it uses a settings file located in the build directory, this can be overridden by setting one of the following variables:

1. MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH
2. MAVEN_SETTINGS_URL